# using node.js to listen for udp datagrams

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, udp

I am working on a project where a C application sends udp datagrams from port 44044 and I would like to use node.js v0.10.20 to simply echo these packets to the console.

I use the classical examples to connect:

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var port = 44044;

socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.on('message', function (msg, info){
    console.log(msg.toString());
 });

socket.on('listening', function(){
    var address = socket.address();
    console.log("listening on :" = address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

socket.bind(port);
```

However, when I run the example, my C application complains that the port 44044 it uses for broadcasts is already in use. Conversely, if I start my C application first, the node.js application returns immediately with an error "Error: bind EADDRINUSE".

Now I understand that this means that I have two servers that are trying to serve on the same port. But what I don't get is how can I get a node thread that will listen to udp broadcasts on port 44044? Reading node.js documentation has not helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SO_REUSEADDR` in your C program and in your node app use:

```
socket = dgram.createSocket({ type: 'udp4', reuseAddr: true });
```

instead of:

```
socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
```

Comment: I tried this until I realised that node 0.10.20 does not support calling dgram.createSocket with an object in signature. I will try updating my version of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

C app sends ***from*** port 44044. What port does it ***send to***? That's the port your `node.js` program needs to listen on.

Comment: I used wrong terminology. When I go into the source code, it seems that it *sends to* port 44044. The reason I say that is because I have another utility that connects to port 44044 and interacts with my C application without problems. The source port is unknown but as far as I understood about udp, it is not compulsory. Could the C application send from and to port 44044 at the same time?